# What is the need to represent the integer value in three different numbering systems?

Tags: java

Eg:

// The number 26, in decimal

```
int decVal = 26;
```

// The number 26, in hexadecimal

```
int hexVal = 0x1a;
```

// The number 26, in binary

```
int binVal = 0b11010;
```

Comment: 4, at least: you forgot octal.

Comment: Because sometimes it is more meaningful or convenient to write the value in a different numbering system.

Comment: Why is your mother language a different one than mine? Wouldnt the world be a much better place if there would be only *one* language for everybody?

Comment: @GhostCat - and that language should be Latin.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get me wrong, but you could as well ask: why are we using Object Oriented programming concepts; such as classes and objects; when we could write down all programs using assembler?

The simple answer is: (as any other language, too) programming languages are **means** to express ideas. The designers of those languages add features that they deem to be **helpful** to those people that will write down source code in the end.

And as you probably know: as soon as you get closer to the "hardware side" of things; bits become important. Many algorithms work on bitwise data; or on bytewise data. Thus there is a certain need to be able to express binary, octal or hex values in simple ways.

Maybe, maybe, when your development work happens *high* up in the stack, then you think only in terms of EJBs, JSON data, XML, and all that "binary" stuff seems far away. But as said; that stack has a "bottom" end as well (or a networking side); and there bits and bytes are deemed so important, that Java, like many other programming languages has distinct means to express the corresponding values.